# Django 1.6 base url (alternative to site framework)?

Tags: django

When sending emails from Django, it's been customary (for me at least) to use the Site object to get the base url.
i.e `'http://{}{}'.format(Site.objects.get_current(), reverse('my_view'))`

However in Django 1.6 the site framework isn't enabled by default, and this got me thinking that perhaps there is a different approach to this now.

Of course, you can add a base url in your settings.py file, but is there a Django specific way to get the base url?

If it was in a template or a view, you could use the `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location)`, however if you use a Celery task to send your emails, then this isn't as straight forward (as you don't have an instance of a HttpRequest object.

So the question is:
What is the most Djangonic way of getting the host, for constructing absolute urls to be used in email (or other areas where you don't have a request object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not feel like it (and a lot of people, myself included, use the sites framework like you describe), but the purpose of Django's site framework isn't that. From the documentation:

> Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.

I believe that's the reason why it's now disabled by default.

As for getting the host in emails, what I would do is store it in the settings:

```
# settings.py
SITE_HOST_NAME = 'example.com'

# email code
from django.conf import settings
SITE_HOST_NAME = getattr(settings, 'SITE_HOST_NAME', 'defaulthostname')
```

As a plus, this approach doesn't hit the database. I'm not sure if it's "the most Djangonic", but it should work.